# Uninstall a Windows Service Framework 3.5 with a command line

Tags: windows-services

I want to know how to uninstall a Windows service build in Framework 3.5 without using the Programs and Features option, I want to use a command line command, any ideas?

Comment: Uninstalling and removing a service from the Services list are two very different things. Which are you wanting to do?

Answer (score -1):

To uninstall the windows service first you can open the visal studio command prompt and run as administrator go to your service file drive and run this command Installuti -u your service name.exe   OR Installutil /u your service name.exe

or create a batch file and run it  :)